# What HTML whitespace is safe to throw away, or safe to add, without changing rendered output?

Tags: html, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I'm working on an HTML formatter (full source code here: https://github.com/kshetline/fortissimo-html). Although I've tried to read through the official HTML specs, I'm still having a hard time nailing down completely the rules for where whitespace is significant, and where it isn't.

There seem to be three categories of whitespace significance:

1. Completely significant - like inside `<pre>` or `<textarea>` tags.
2. All contiguous whitespace is treated as a single space, with leading and trailing whitespace, if any, preserved as a single space.
3. Leading and trailing whitespace is trimmed away, all other whitespace is collapsed into a single space, as above. In this category nothing but whitespace is trimmed down to nothing at all.

I'm clear on `<pre>` and `<textarea>` belonging to category 1.

I'm clear on formatting tags like `<i>` and `<strong>`, etc., and `<span>` as well, belonging to category 2.

I'm also clear on the content of tags like `<p>`, `<td>`, and `<li>` belonging to category 3.

Where it gets more confusing for me is in between tags like those above. It seems clear (but only by example) that whitespace between table elements doesn't matter (although non-whitespace, which doesn't properly belong there, does some weird things).

Whitespace does, however, oddly matter inside `<ul>` and `<ol>` tags (often to the annoyance of people using `<ul>`/`<li>` markup for menus and nav bars).

So, if I'm reformatting HTML either to make it prettier with nice indentation, or to condense it and remove as much whitespace as possible, what's a good guide to where I...

1. ...must leave at least one space if there was originally whitespace...
2. ...can safely add whitespace, even if there wasn't any whitespace there to begin with...

...and not change how a typical browser renders the final HTML?

(By the way, I'm aware that CSS can change the behavior of almost any tag to, say, act like a `<pre>` tag, but I'm only concerned with general rules where there are no CSS modifications, or very common cases like inlined `<ul>`/`<li>`.)

[image]

```css
table {
  display: inline-table;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <span>One</span>
  <span>Two</span>
  <span>Three</span><span>Four</span>
  <table>x
    <tr>
      <td>  1  </td>   <td>  2  </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>y
  </table>z
  <br>
  <ul>
    <li>Foo
    <li>   Bar</li>
    <li>Baz</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

https://codepen.io/kshetline/pen/KKKKZVK

Comment: Browsers render only one space inside HTML content, all other spaces are ignored by default. For adding more than one space you can use non breaking space: &nbsp;

Comment: From an html perspective, none*. What you are describing is CSS behavior, and this will depend on the computed styles of your elements. (* well actually the ones in-between attributes will get removed at parsing.)

Comment: @Massood, things like `&nbsp;` aren't the issue here for me, and I already described as known to me how sequences of whitespace are treated as a single space. @Kaiido, I already alluded to the role of CSS above, but (1) an HTML formatter mainly needs to deal with *default* CSS for various elements (with it being up to the person using a formatter to be careful if their CSS changes things), and (2) some things, like the treatment of whitespace between table elements, aren't easily nailed down to CSS (`<textarea>` behavior is perhaps even a better example).

Comment: Once again, from an html perspective, (almost) all these white-spaces do matter. So if you really just want an HTML answer, then it's simply "Only the space characters following a space character when in between two attributes declarations." All others **are** significant and kept.

Comment: @Kaiido, all of the other spaces and newlines aren't typically kept *and rendered*, and that's the point. Whether from a purist standpoint all the stuff is stored inside the DOM is largely moot. There are other HTML formatters (I just want to write my own to do a few things a little differently), and they clearly try to follow *general rules* about where they do or do not modify whitespace, and in what ways, without being CSS processors. The other HTML formatters *do not* give up and say, "Gosh, it's all up to CSS. I better not touch this whitespace at all!".

Comment: Those choices aren't arbitrary. I'm looking for the general rules other creators of HTML formatters would have been likely to follow, based on what typical browsers do with rendering whitespace under typical circumstances.

Comment: These choices are plain arbitrary. The specs are very clear, these white-spaces are kept at parsing (`\r` being a special beast, which is [removed at parsing](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#normalize-newlines)). There is nothing like "general rules", you have to define these yourself, and there is no "typical circumstances" either, unless you define the restrictions that will avoid special cases.

Comment: Sure there are typical cases: Like the case of HTML with no CSS modifications at all. I've experimented with different browsers, and found that they all typically render whitespace in much the same way. Plus, I'm getting the definite impression some of the whitespace handling is beyond the reach of CSS...

Comment: ..., like whether leading/trailing space is rendered. By default, a `<td>` tag removes all leading and trailing space. There's no CSS that describes that behavior (at least that I've found anywhere). CSS lets you decide whether that space is treated like a single space, or if it's all significant (`white-space: pre`), but I see no CSS related to completely trimming leading and trailing space.

Answer (score 2):

For the purposes of this discussion, whitespace is as defined here: https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ascii-whitespace

> ASCII whitespace is U+0009 TAB, U+000A LF, U+000C FF, U+000D CR, or U+0020 SPACE.

Non-breaking whitespace and other Unicode space characters are handled very much like any other non-space character. (U+000B might also go along for the ride as whitespace, even though it's not listed above.)

So, from what I've determined so far, this is my best understanding now of HTML whitespace handling:

1. `<textarea>` is a special case where *almost* all of the whitespace inside is significant, because it directly affects the value assigned to the textarea as an input field. While the rendering of this element can be changed via CSS, whitespace remains significant to the value of the input regardless of rendering.
2. `<pre>`, of course, is specifically designed to make *almost* all whitespace significant in how text will be rendered.
3. The reason I used the word "almost" above is because leading and trailing newlines are an exception. A single leading newline or single trailing newline will be ignored. Two newlines are required (leading or trailing) to have a single newline rendered (or, in the case of `<textarea>` to have a single newline become part of the input value). From what I can tell, this special newline handling goes beyond what can be specified via CSS. Within any other element, single newlines alone take effect if you use CSS `whitespace: pre` and relating styling. (See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/kshetline/a510tq4v)

[image: pre tag vs. white-space: pre]

4. `<script>` and `<style>` tags are obviously special cases, with language-specific whitespace significance. Except for the content of quoted values, however, and the newline needed at the end of a JavaScript line comment (`//`), all whitespace can be either reduced to a single whitespace, or omitted where not syntactically required.
5. Whitespace inside CDATA sections should be left as is, although it may or may not render depending on circumstances.
6. Whitespace is all significant inside quoted attribute values.

Setting aside the above cases, or the application of the CSS `whitespace` property, all contiguous sequences of whitespace will otherwise be treated the same way: as a single whitespace. Three spaces, twenty newlines, a dozen alternating form-feed and tab characters, it's all the same as a single space.

7. No whitespace is allowed between the `<` that starts a tag and the tag's name, e.g. `<br>` works, but `< br>` doesn't. Without belaboring the point, it's fairly obvious that extra spacing can prevent an end tag, a comment, etc., from parsing correctly as well.
8. Whitespace is needed syntactically to separate tag names from attribute names, and attribute names from other attribute names and attribute values where quoting doesn't make that separation clear.

Now here's the real meat of the subject that I was trying to get at for performing HTML reformatting without affecting how the HTML is typically rendered by most browsers:

9. In contrast to what I'll refer to as *block* elements, formatting elements like `<b>` or `<code>` or `<strong>`, and the `<span>` element as well, are *inline* elements. Here's a list of inline elements, as it appears in the code I'm currently working on, obtained mostly from the HTML formatting settings of Intellij IDEA:

```
  inline: new Set(['a', 'abbr', 'acronym', 'b', 'basefont', 'bdo', 'big', 'br', 'cite', 'cite', 'code', 'dfn',
                   'em', 'font', 'i', 'img', 'input', 'kbd', 'label', 'q', 's', 'samp', 'select', 'small', 'span',
                   'strike', 'strong', 'sub', 'sup', 'text', 'tt', 'u', 'var']),
```

For text within inline elements, all interior contiguous whitespace is treated as a single space. Leading space is trimmed when it is at the start of a block element, or immediately follows a block element. Trailing space is trimmed when it is at the end of a block element, or immediately precedes a block element. For the purposes of rendering, a CDATA section is treated inline as far a neighboring text is concerned.

Consider:

`<p> Hello,<i> world!</i> </p> It's Tuesday.`

The space in front of "Hello" will not be rendered, because it's at the start of a block. The space in front of "world", however, will be rendered. The space after `</i>` will not be rendered, because it's at the end of a block. The space in front of "It's" will not be rendered, because it follows a block.

Now consider this:

`<p>I'm <b> not </b> going to pay a lot for this muffler.</p>`

The space after "I'm" and the space before "not" will together be treated as a single space. So will the space after "not" and the space before "going". Which spaces are kept, and which are thrown away? A little CSS styling, giving `<b>` a background color, reveals the leading spaces being discarded in favor of the trailing spaces:

[image: whitespace handling screenshot]

This appears consistent using Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE, and Edge.

And now a really simple example:

```
<div>                 tree    
     bark           </div>
```

None of that leading or trailing spaces matters — it won't be rendered. No leading space, no trailing space, no additional line breaks. Just "tree bark".

Comment: Thank you for the followup on your own question, great explanation!